# i am trying to run create-react-app how can i avoid error

Tags: npm

> ```
> acuff@Big-Morty:/mnt/c/Users/Christian/Documents/my-app$ npx create-react-app my-app
> : not foundram Files/nodejs/npx: 3: /mnt/c/Program Files/nodejs/npx: 
> : not foundram Files/nodejs/npx: 5: /mnt/c/Program Files/nodejs/npx: 
> /mnt/c/Program Files/nodejs/npx: 6: /mnt/c/Program Files/nodejs/npx: Syntax error: word unexpected (expecting "in")
> ```

Comment: This question lacks a lot of context. It's a bit unclear what you're asking. Also, the error message seems to be incomplete. Please format your question, include the entire error message and also the relevant code parts.

Comment: If you just installed node/npm try restarting your console

Comment: Install npx on your terminal with: sudo npm install -g npx. Then restart the shell